# JavaFX, swap anchorpane element with FXML from another file

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create a dynamic UI in JavaFX similar to the picture below, The menu on the left will be contained inside its own anchorpane, while the currently selected item will determine what is populated in the right anchorpane.

Using this layout I want to be able to swap the entire right anchorpane out with an anchorpane I will declare in a separate file, to try to keep it all modular. Is this the preferred method over declaring it all in the same file and simply hiding it when not in use? If this is the proper method how do you go about doing it?

[image]

The question is a little broad but I haven't been able to find any references that show how to do the above, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a new FXML document and set it as the child for your right-side `AnchorPane`.

Below is a very rough sample application that shows the concept in action.  Basically, the work is done in the `loadPage()` method, which you'll want to adapt to your usage as this sample is just meant to show the concept only.

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainLayout.fxml"));
            loader.setController(new MainController());

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

---

**MainLayout.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
            prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
        <AnchorPane fx:id="paneMainContent" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"
                    style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 2px;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"/>
    </center>
    <left>
        <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
            </rowConstraints>
            <VBox fx:id="vboxShowCats" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0"
                  style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 2px;">
                <Button fx:id="btnShowCats" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show Cats"/>
            </VBox>
            <VBox fx:id="vboxShowDogs" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0"
                  style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 2px;" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                <Button fx:id="btnShowDogs" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show Dogs"/>
            </VBox>
            <VBox fx:id="vboxShowBirds" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0"
                  style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 2px;" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                <Button fx:id="btnShowBirds" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show Birds"/>
            </VBox>
        </GridPane>
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```

---

**MainController.java**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane paneMainContent;
    @FXML
    private VBox vboxShowCats;
    @FXML
    private Button btnShowCats;
    @FXML
    private VBox vboxShowDogs;
    @FXML
    private Button btnShowDogs;
    @FXML
    private VBox vboxShowBirds;
    @FXML
    private Button btnShowBirds;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        btnShowCats.setOnAction(event -> loadPage("Cats"));
        btnShowDogs.setOnAction(event -> loadPage("Dogs"));
        btnShowBirds.setOnAction(event -> loadPage("Birds"));

    }

    private void loadPage(String name) {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(name + "View.fxml"));

            AnchorPane newPane = loader.load();

            // Set the loaded FXML file as the content of our main right-side pane
            paneMainContent.getChildren().setAll(newPane);

            // Reset the anchors
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(newPane, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(newPane, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(newPane, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(newPane, 0.0);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**CatsView.fxml, DogsView.fxml, BirdsView.fxml** *All identical except for the `Label`:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
          AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <Label style="-fx-font-size: 200%;" text="These are CATS!"/>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

---

> **The Result:**

[image: screenshot]

I'm sure there are more advanced (and preferable) methods of accomplishing this, but it does work and it's how I've done it (though I'm still learning myself).

Also, I obviously did not bother to style the example :)